# Limited functioning outlets

Tags: receptacle

Two outlets in my den (on a 2 pole 30 amp circuit) stopped powering my sewing machine and laptop. They still power small items such as a desk lamp and phone charger. Since they previously worked fine my question is will replacing the outlets fix this issue?

Comment: What you mean on a 30 amp circuit?  Is the breaker 30 amps(big no-no) or two 15 amps breakers(or a double 15)?

Comment: We need more information in order to help, starting with why residential outlets would be on a 30A circuit. That's just not right. Then, it makes no sense that "small" devices work and others don't. Please revise with that, along with information about your home such as age, region, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped powering"? Does the voltage go to zero or what?

Comment: A picture of the breaker in question would help clarify the "2 pole 30 amp circuit" confusion. Also, a picture of the wiring on the outlets in question (turn the breaker off _first_ and don't disconnect any wiring in the junction box!) would be helpful, as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are things that seem odd here as menationed in comments. Hopefully that's a dual 15, not a 30 of any sort for the breaker.

You have the symptoms of a poor/loose connection somewhere on the circuit. such a connection appears to be connected, but has a high resistance compared to wire or a good connection. For a load that only uses a little current, a few volts are dropped by the resistance of the poor connection, but not enough to stop it working. For a load that draws more current, enough voltage is lost at the bad connection to cause the higher-current load to stop working. Meanwhile, the poor connection is being heated, making it a fire hazard to your house.

One common cause of poor connections in many houses is the use of "backstab" wiring on receptacles, which is inferior to screwed-down connections. Other common causes are poorly installed wirenuts (Marrettes.)

If some outlets on the circuit work fine, and others do not, the poor connection will normally either be at the wires going onward from the last good outlet, or the wires coming in to the first bad outlet, as the circuit runs.

Replacing the outlets *might* fix the issure, if in replacing the outlets the poor connection is redone as a better connection, but it's not likely to be the case that you have a bad outlet causing the problem - so simply going over the connections (and, if applicable, moving any "backstab" wires to their corresponding side screws) is as likely to solve it without buying new outlets (receptacles) unless there's an obvious problem with the plug connecting to the receptacle (the receptacle is loose when you plug in, the plug falls out, you open it up and find the area near the backstabs is charred or melted, etc.)

Comment: Re that last point: Sometimes it's simply a worn-out outlet making sloppy contact with plugs, such that plugs with certain kinds of spring to their blades make decent contact and others don't. If so, you should be able to feel that the plug is looser in the outlet than it is in other outlets where the device works more reliably. In that case, replacing the outlet would be the fix.